# How to reflect an image diagonally in java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I have the following code in order to reflect an image diagonally:

```
public void mirrorDiagonal() {

      Pixel[][] pixels = this.getPixels2D();

      Pixel topRightPixel = null;
      Pixel bottomLeftPixel = null;
      int maxLength;
      if (pixels.length < pixels[0].length) { maxLength = pixels.length; }
      else {maxLength = pixels[0].length; }

      for (int row = 0; row < maxLength; row++)
      {
          for (int col = row; col < maxLength; col++)
          {
              topRightPixel = pixels[row][col];
              bottomLeftPixel = pixels[col][row];
              bottomLeftPixel.setColor(topRightPixel.getColor());
          }
      }
  }
```

However I messed up somewhere and it reflects the image from the top right of the image to the bottom left.

My Question: How would I reflect it any other way? (more specifically from the top left to the bottom right)

Comment: Your code only works on squares. Was that your intention or do you need it to work on other formats as well? Also you need to swap the colors. Which requires two `setColor` operations, not one.

Comment: Try `bottomLeftPixel = -pixels[row][col];`

Comment: `pixels[row][col]` is an object, not a number. You can't negate it.

Comment: Bleh. You're right. Negate the coordinates of the pixel.

Comment: @SpiderPig yes it is only supposed to work on squares, and why would I need two setColor operations?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the pixel that you think is the top right is actually the top left.  Try the following instead:

```
for (int row = 0; row < maxLength; row++) {
    for (int col = maxLength - row - 1; col >= 0; col--) {
        topRightPixel = pixels[row][col];
        bottomLeftPixel = pixels[col][row];
        bottomLeftPixel.setColor(topRightPixel.getColor());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you change the colors? You could instead move the pixel objects. Also if you define 3 basic transformations, you can construct all the others by combining the first 3 in different ways.
e.g.

```
static void mirrorHor(Pixel[][] pixels) {
  for(int row = 0; row < pixels.length; row++) {
    for(int col = 0; col + col < pixels[row].length - 1; col++) {
      Pixel p = pixels[row][col];
      pixels[row][col] = pixels[row][pixels[row].length - col - 1];
      pixels[row][pixels[row].length - col - 1] = p;
    }
  }
}

static void mirrorVert(Pixel[][] pixels) {
  for(int row = 0; row + row < pixels.length - 1; row++) {
    Pixel[] r = pixels[row];
    pixels[row] = pixels[pixels.length - row - 1];
    pixels[pixels.length - row - 1] = r;
  }
}

static void mirrorTopRightBottomLeft(Pixel[][] pixels) {
  for(int row = 0; row < pixels.length - 1; row++) {
    for(int col = row + 1; col < pixels.length; col++) {
      Pixel p = pixels[row][col];
      pixels[row][col] = pixels[col][row];
      pixels[col][row] = p;
    }
  }
}

static void rotate180(Pixel[][] pixels) {
  mirrorHor(pixels);
  mirrorVert(pixels);
}

static void mirrorTopLeftBottomRight(Pixel[][] pixels) {
  mirrorTopRightBottomLeft(pixels);
  rotate180(pixels);
}

static void rotateLeft90(Pixel[][] pixels) {
  mirrorTopRightBottomLeft(pixels);
  mirrorVert(pixels);
}

static void rotateRight90(Pixel[][] pixels) {
  mirrorTopRightBottomLeft(pixels);
  mirrorHor(pixels);
}
```